# Connecting to Twilio API using PHP

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

The example code asks for a `$sid` and `$token`.

I logged in to my account and went to Dev Tools → API Keys and created a new key which generated a `Sid` and `Secret`.

I went back to Account Settings → API Credentials and I have a `AccountSID` and `AuthToken` but the `AccountSID` is not the same as the `Sid` shown at Dev Tools → API Keys.

So I have 4 different strings, what am I suppose to do with them? What is the `$sid` that the example code asks for, is it the `Sid` in Dev Tools - API Keys or the `AccountSID` in Account Settings → API Credentials, and what on earth is the `$token`, I don't see this anywhere?

I've tried using a mixture on the below example code, with PHP error logging enabled, but it just causes the page to load as `Server Error 500`.

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = ""; 
$token = ""; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Loop over the list of numbers and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->incoming_phone_numbers as $number) {
    echo "<select>" . $number->phone_number . "</select>";
}
```

*Side note: Does Twilio charge for API calls (actual API usage, not purchasing etc.)?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can see how that got confusing. For what you're trying to do, you can just grab the AccountSid and AuthToken from your [dashboard](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/voice/dashboard). Once you're there, just expand "Show API Credentials" and copy the values.

[image]

As for your question, Twilio will not charge for requests like the one you're trying to make. Worth having a look at our [billing and pricing FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/HELP/faq/billing-pricing) to get some more information.

Hope this helps you

Comment: There is going to be a time where you can use that API Key and API Secret as credentials, but I couldn't get it to work with the Twilio PHP library myself. For now, using Account SID and Auth Token is the right way :)

Comment: @Marcos Placona Thanks. I am building an app to send/receive SMS messages and also I will need to list the numbers (as original question) so I take it that I do not need to use Dev Tools → API Keys method and can go ahead and delete that key that I created?

Comment: Correct. For now, you can just use the AccountSid and AuthToken. in the future, we will sunset that and use API Keys for everything.